# Interprocess communication between Inno setups via Pipe cannot create Pipe

Tags: inno-setup, communication, named-pipes, interprocess

I would like to separate a huge Inno setup into smaller packages which give their progress and state to the "master" setup. The sub-setups shall be called silent/hidden so that only one window is in front and integrates the progress of all others into one (total)progressbar.
I've tried to intercommunicate via the Windows pipe system, but even creating a named pipe fails. I've used "\\.\pipe\SetupMsPipe123" and while debugging it showed correctly in the given variable. Even additional escaping like "\\\\.\\pipe\\SetupMsPipe123" failed.
The return value of the function seems to be an INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE but the Inno variable seems only to hold 4 bytes of the 8 byte handle value.
Possibly there is something wrong with the type conversion between the variables.

(Updated with the suggestions of TLama)

```
[Code]   {BOTH}
type
#ifdef UNICODE
    #define AW "W"
#else
    #define AW "A"
#endif
#define DefPipeName  "\\.\pipe\SetupMsPipe123"
var
    mhPipeHandle:   THandle;
    msPipeName  :   string;
type LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES = Cardinal; function CreateNamedPipe(lpName: string; dwOpenMode, dwPipeMode, nMaxInstances, nOutBufferSize, nInBufferSize, nDefaultTimeOut: DWORD; lpSecurityAttributes: LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES): THandle;
  external 'CreateNamedPipe{#AW}@kernel32.dll stdcall';
function WaitNamedPipe(lpNamedPipeName: string; nTimeOut: DWORD): Boolean;
  external 'WaitNamedPipe{#AW}@kernel32 stdcall';
function ConnectNamedPipe(hNamedPipe: THandle; lpOverlapped: LongWord): Boolean;
  external 'ConnectNamedPipe@kernel32 stdcall';
function DisconnectNamedPipe(hNamedPipe: THandle): Boolean;
  external 'DisconnectNamedPipe@kernel32 stdcall';
function CreateFile(lpFileName: string; dwDesiredAccess,dwShareMode: DWORD; lpSecurityAttributes: LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES; dwCreationDisposition,dwFlagsAndAttributes: DWORD; hTemplateFile: THandle): LongWord;
  external 'CreateFile{#AW}@kernel32 stdcall';
function ReadFile(hFile: THandle; lpBuffer: string; nNumberOfBytesToRead: DWORD; var lpNumberOfBytesRead: LongWord; var lpOverlapped: LongWord): Boolean;
  external 'ReadFile@kernel32 stdcall';
function WriteFile(hFile: THandle; lpBuffer: string; nNumberOfBytesToWrite: DWORD; var lpNumberOfBytesWritten: LongWord; var lpOverlapped: LongWord): Boolean;
  external 'WriteFile@kernel32 stdcall';
function CloseHandle(hObject: THandle): Boolean;
  external 'CloseHandle@kernel32 stdcall';
function GetLastError(): DWORD;
  external 'GetLastError@kernel32 stdcall';

[Code]   {MASTER}
procedure InitializeWizard();
var 
  lcbProgress: longword;
  lcbFilename: longword;
  bStat:       Boolean;
  lpPipename:  string;
begin
  msPipeName := ExpandConstant('{#DefPipeName}');
  mhPipeHandle := dllCreateNamedPipe(msPipeName, PIPE_ACCESS_INBOUND, PIPE_TYPE_BYTE or PIPE_NOWAIT, 2, 1024, 1024, 60000, 0);
  if mhPipeHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then begin    
    bStat := dllConnectNamedPipe(mhPipeHandle, 0);
  end;
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
var
  iProgressInner: integer;
  bStat:          Boolean;
  acReadBuffer:   string;
  dwBufLen:       DWORD;
  dwBytesRead:    DWORD;
  dwOverlapped:   DWORD;
begin
  SetLength(acReadBuffer, 1024);
  if CurStep = ssInstall then begin
    Exec('setupInner.exe', '', '', SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ResultCode);
    while (iProgressInner<100) do begin
      bStat := ReadFile(mhPipeHandle, acReadBuffer, Length(acReadBuffer), dwBytesRead, dwOverlapped);
      iProgressInner := StrToInt(acReadBuffer);
      WizardForm.Caption:='Progress: ' + IntToStr(iProgressInner);
      WizardForm.Refresh();
      Sleep (1000)     
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure DeinitializeSetup();
begin 
  DisconnectNamedPipe(mhPipeHandle);
  CloseHandle(mhPipeHandle);
end;

[code]  {Slave}
function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
var
  bStat:          Boolean;
  lpOutBuffer:    LongWord;
  nOutBufferSize: DWORD;
  lpBytesRead:    LongWord;
begin
  msPipeName := ExpandConstant('{#DefPipeName}');
  bStat := WaitNamedPipe(msPipeName, 60000);
  mhPipeHandle := CreateFile(msPipeName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
  Result := true;
end;

procedure CurInstallProgressChanged(CurProgress, MaxProgress: Integer);
var                   
  iProgress:      integer;
  bStat:          Boolean;
  acWriteBuffer:  String;
  dwBufLen:       DWORD;
  dwWritten:      DWORD;
  dwOverlapped:   DWORD;
  sTemp:          String;
begin
  sTemp := IntToStr(CurProgress);    
  while Length(sTemp) < 3 do begin
    sTemp := '0' + sTemp;
  end;
  acWriteBuffer := sTemp;
// Here the exception occurs !!! 
  bStat := WriteFile(mhPipeHandle, acWriteBuffer,    Length(acWriteBuffer), dwWritten, dwOverlapped); 
end;
```

Comment: Handle is 32-bit, not 64-bit (there is the `THandle` type available). Inno Setup does not use backslash escaping. What is suspicious in your code is that `AnsiString` type used for the `lpName` parameter. If you are using Unicode Inno Setup, this will fail (because you would be calling `CreateNamedPipeW` variant of the function which expects a Unicode input). Try to run this http://pastebin.com/6hZyvPZE.

Comment: Yep, that did it. The pipe seems to be created as expected but now i'm just not able to write to it. It throws an "Access violation ... in module KERNELBASE.dll. Write of adress 00000000". So the Master perfoms these steps: `code` CreateNamedPipe - ConnectNamedPipe - ReadFile - DisconnectNamedPipe - CloseHandle

Comment: And the Slave: `code` WaitNamedPipe - CreateFile - **WriteFile** - CloseHandle       I used a string as writebuffer which holds "001" which should represent the progress in percent.

Comment: I can't see your code, so I cannot help. But wouldn't be better to create a small library for this stuff (and use e.g. Windows messages if it's just about updating a progress).

Comment: Code updated. Perspectively not only the progress, but also the currently processed filename, error states, or other feasible information has to be passed to the master. That's the reason for using pipe or shared memory principles.

Comment: OK the access violation seems to occur because the call by reference (which i didn't know for Pascal). Now it doesn't crash any mor but i have to check why the data is not passed properly. Thank you TLama for the support.